# Xdebug unable to read Dotenv.php

Tags: php, vagrant, symfony4, xdebug, homestead

The environment:

- PHP - v7.4
- Symfony - v4.1
- Vagrant - v2.2.7
- Homestead - v9.5.1
- VSCode

My `launch.json` file configuration:

```
     {
         "name": "Listen for myapp",
         "type": "php",
         "request": "launch",
         "port": 9000,
         "pathMappings": {
              "/home/vagrant/code": "/home/user/code",
              "/home/vagrant/code/myapp": "/home/user/code/myapp",
              "/home/vagrant/code/myapp/public": "/home/user/code/myapp/public"
            },
      },
```

My `Homestead.yaml` file:

```yaml
     - map: myapp.test
          to: /home/vagrant/code/myapp/public
          type: symfony4
```

My `xdebug.ini` config (located in `/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`):

```
    zend_extension=xdebug.so
    xdebug.remote_enable=1
    xdebug.remote_autostart=1
    xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

When I am running `xdebugger` (VSCode PHP debug extension), it is showing

```
>Unable to open 'Dotenv.php': Unable to read file '/home/vagrant/code/myapp/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/home/vagrant/code/myapp/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php').
```

Can anyone give any guidance on it?

**Update 1:**

It seems it is unable to read this line itself:

```
    (new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');
```

`.env` file has permission `644`, I tried changing it to `775` and tried again but still got same issue.

Both location of `.env` and `Dotenv.php` is correct, currently `.env` has permission `644` and `Dotenv.php` has `775`.

Comment: Could you please do a `var_dump(__DIR__.'/../.env');` before your `load()`? To check if the path are created in the right way.

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes thank you for your reply, let me try and update here.

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes I got "/home/vagrant/code/g4-middleware-symfony/public/../.env".

Comment: And your file in vagrant points to the same place? If not, I believe that this is the problem.

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes Can you explain little bit whatever I have configured and all the mappings I have posted.

Comment: The error `Unable to read file '/home/vagrant/code/myapp/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php'` seems to be that your file not exists. So, seems to be an error inside your mapping. Another thing is: Do you have been run the `composer install`?

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes I have verified Dotenv.php file is there and .env also I have udpated in question with permission.

Comment: Thanks: As your error put this: `Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/home/vagrant/code/myapp/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php'`, this seems to be a mapping error. Can you access your vagrant install and check if the path already exists inside your vagrant container?

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes yes, the path is vagrant/code inside vagrant machine and /code in original system no difference, Am I making any mistake in `lunch.json` as just setup a laravel application and it worked perfectly, the xdebugger is working perfectly for laravel, but the pathmapping is no different for laravel too, it is totally same as symfony public folder.sorry for late reply, the current was out.

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes I got the issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having 4 applications, all of them having `launch.json` with respective `pathmappings` and I added all of them to a workspace, so the default configurations that got generated were same in all `launch.json` and it was creating confusion for `xdebug` config. Removed all `launch.json` and created one for the whole workspace and the problem got resolved.